# Functionality of c static library in cpp dll

Tags: c++, c, dll

I have some functionality, for example:

header.h

```
void printFunc();
```

staticLib.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

void printFunc()
{
    printf("Hello from C static lib");
}
```

I need to usethis functionality in cpp dll. I create win32 project file, choose dll. In created project i:

-add dll path in Configuration properties-> C/C++ -> General-> Additional Include Directory

-add dll name into Configuration properties-> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.

And my solution still not working. I get error, that cannot open .lib file.

How I can fix it?

Comment: Blind guess: permissions?

Comment: `CPP` is the C PreProcessor. If you mean C++, please write that!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have not added the lib path to The Library Directory.

Comment: isn't it Configuration properties-> C/C++ -> General-> Additional Include Directory?